# JVM heap parameters in Linux OS

Tags: java, linux, jvm

Can anyone suggest the command to check the JVM heap parameters in Linux Operating System? I want to see the `-Xms<memory>` `-Xmx<memory>` parameters of Java JVM installed in the Linux OS.

Can anyone suggest the Linux command for this?

Regards
Deb

Answer (score 0):

Below command would tell default Heapsize limitations of installed Java.

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep 'HeapSize'
```

**Edit:**

Sample Output:

```
[user1@orion ~]$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep 'HeapSize'
    uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0               {product}           
    uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520        {product}           
    uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 93115136        {product}           
    uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728       {product}           
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 1491075072      {product}           
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.10.5.0.1.el5_9-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I tried it but it is not working. It is not showing the HeapSize values.